# Jinja2 setting and using variables

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have the following

```
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                {% if datas|length > 0 %}
                {% set longest = [] %}
                {% for data in datas %}
                {% if data['numbers']|length > longest|length %}
                {% set longest = data['numbers'] %}
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% for i in longest %}
                <th></th>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

I am trying to make enough headers to accommodate the longest list of numbers in the datas dictionary.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Chris

Comment: What is actual problem/error/wrong result?

Comment: There are no headers being created. If I insert `<th>{{ longest }}</th>` after the first loops `{% endfor %}`. I get a header with the title `[]`. So it seems maybe the variable I am creating is getting cleared.